# Required permissions to reorder Azure Devops Board items

Tags: azure-devops

In my organization, I have a user who will serve as "project manager". I want to give her the ability to move items around on the Kanban "Board", assign personnel to user stories and tasks, and generally be in charge of dealing with the DevOps project management artifacts.

I'm trying to figure out the permissions I need to give her in Azure DevOps. I've put her in the **Contributors** project group.

- If I give her **Stakeholder** access level then she can move board items from one column to another, but she cannot move board items up or down within the same column or change the personnel assigned to an item.
- If I give her **Basic** access level then she has full editing access to the board, including the ability to move items up or down within the same column.

Do I really need to give users **Basic** access level for them to be able to serve as project managers, with the ability to add items, edit items, reorder items, assign personnel to items, and otherwise deal with project management features?

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops)? The two scenarios you mentioned are specifically unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Daniel Mann (see the comment on the OP), [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops) clearly state that **Basic** access level is required to:

- Change the priority of an item within a board
- Change fields on cards on a board, except for State field

Comment: Did you mean "Stakeholder access level user cannot" instead of Basic?